# Translation of a sentence

Tags: objetos-indirectos

What is the meaning of the two "la" words following the 'que" in the sentence

> Podías decirle a uno de ellos que **la** siguieran pero no **la** podían ver.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it means, "you could ask one of them to follow/track **her**, but they couldn't see **her**"

As you can see, we are referring to "her" twice, so we have used the pronoun `la` twice for it in the original sentence. In your example there is a couple of subordinate sentences (introduced by those "que").

> Podías decirle a uno de ellos que **la** siguieran pero (ellos) no **la** podían ver
>
> Podías decirle a uno de ellos que **la** siguieran pero no  podían ver**la**
>
> Podías decirle a uno de ellos que siguieran **a la mujer**  pero no  podían ver **a la mujer**

Note: in the last case, that `la` is an article instead of a pronoun. In the others `la` stands for "la mujer", "la chica", "la persona" or that who *"they where asked to follow but they couldn't see*".